# Monerod created a transaction with no sender and 0 fee, still this transaction was confirmed

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc, transaction-data, full-node

Somehow happend, that after regular request to the RPC for creating a new transaction, my local node created transaction that has no sender and 0 fee, but this transaction on current has over 6k confirmations.

Also the recipients list is not correct and contains more than 500 unknown recipients, but should be only 1. The amount is still correct, the one that was specified.

I have two questions:

- Why was this transaction not canceled by the network?
- What possible errors could lead to this behavior?

P.S.: I'm using RPC as an endpoint for my application, so first of all, this was not a request that I initiated myself. Anyway, I have all the data used (or at least should have been used) to create this transaction: sender address, recipient address, and amount.

[image]

Comment: monerod doesn't *create* transactions. Instead of a screenshot, please update your question with details like your usage of the wallet RPC, the block / transaction you're concerned with etc etc

Comment: Помогите у меня точно такая же ситуация!!!
Help, I have exactly the same situation!!!